Notify navbar of authenticated status when logged in (Angular)
I'm using an nx monorepo (Angular/NestJS), and when I log in (using the login component), I want the navbar (in a different lib) to print out the username, and conditionally, the Log out button. In the auth.service.ts, I created 2 BehaviourSubjects, which I manipulate, and 2 public observables, on which I can subscribe to, in other components (like navbar):
 private isAuthenticatedSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(
    this.hasToken()
  );

  private currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<{
    username: string;
    roles: string[];
  }>(this.getUserFromToken());

  isAuthenticated$: Observable<boolean> =
    this.isAuthenticatedSubject.asObservable();
  currentUser$: Observable<{ username: string; roles: string[] }> =
    this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();

And when the login happens, I notify these 2 private BehaviorSubjects about it:
  public login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.apiURL}/login`, { username, password }).pipe(
      tap((response: any) => {
        if (response.token) {
          this.onLoginHandle(response.token);
        }
      })
    );
  }

  public onLoginHandle(token: string) {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(true);

    of(null)
      .pipe(
        delay(0), // Small delay to ensure token is set
        tap(() => {
          const user = this.getUserFromToken();
          this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
          this.router.navigate(['../']);
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
private getUserFromToken() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      const decodedToken: any = jwt_decode.jwtDecode(token);
      return {
        username: decodedToken.user,
        roles: decodedToken.roles || [],
      };
    } else {
      return {
        username: '',
        roles: [],
      };
    }
  }

The login method is, what I call, when I submit the login form.
Now in the navbar, I created 2 properties (username, to print the logged in user's username, and isLoggedIn, which handles the *ngIf directive on the 'Logout' button). I subscribed both on the isAuthenticated$ and the currentUser$ BehaviourSubject:
  public username: string;
  public isLoggedIn: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isAuthenticatedSub = this.authService.isAuthenticated$.subscribe(
      (isAuthenticated) => {
        this.isLoggedIn = isAuthenticated;
      }
    );

    this.currentUsersub = this.authService.currentUser$.subscribe({
      next: (user) => {
        console.log('Received user data in navbar:', user);
        this.username = user.username;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      },
      error: (error: HttpErrorResponse): void => {
        console.error('Error receiving user data:', error);
      },
    });
  }

But after the login is successful, and the app navigates to the homepage, the navbar (which is there from the start) still does not show the username, nor the Logout button. But if I refresh the page, they are there. Why does the subscription to these 2 auth properties does not behave the way I want? Did i miss something? The console.log('Received user data in navbar:', user); runs only at page reload, though i think, it should run every time, the value of the currentUser$ changes (like, right at login).

please share the code for getUserFromToken if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated or a github repo

@NarenMurali  I added it to the question. The project is private, I cannot share the repo, unfortunately :(

I think you have SSR enabled, could you wrap the html code in a defer block, or use isPlatformBrowser to make the HTML render only on the browser, this might solve your issue

@NarenMurali the navbar itself is just az nx library, I think, SSR is not even able to be used for libs. The angular app (NQO app for example, in my case), which uses this navbar lib, does not have SSR enabled. Though I tried what you said, it did not help (but at least I learnt about defer too)

does the navbar have OnPush Change detection? or have CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA enabled?

@NarenMurali no, I've used none of these (though now I checked them, what are they good for). As after page reload, navbar (which is a standalone component, not sure if that matters), gets the most recent data, so it seems like it's just not correctly subscribed to the BehaviourSubject (or is not notified, when its value is being changed)

I think I solved it, the service emit is not received by the navbar, since the library has its own instance of authService. Instead create a service inside the nav library like navbar service. Then directly import this service in your application (wiithout adding to any providers) then the emit will be recevied by the navbar

@NarenMurali I dont quite get it. I cannot import service (with Injectable decorator) to any module/standalone component, I only can use it in their "providers" array, if im correct. I tried 2 ways tho:
1: to create navbar service, subscribe to the auth.service BehaviourSubjects, and inject navbar service in the navbar component
2: subscribed to the auth.service's Beh.Subj in the app's (NQO) service, and injected that service in the app.component
but none worked.

you can set the service to providedIn: 'root' and use the service without adding in providers array, also add console.log and confirm the subscribe is getting called

@NarenMurali yep, now it works, thank you!!! So basically, the navbar (which is a static lib) only instanciates the authService, does not "dynamically" subscribes to its BehaviourSubject. For that, a separate service (NavbarService, in my case) needs to be implemented. Thanks a lot!

Since the navbar is its own library, it mostly has a different instance of authService so the subject it not receiving the event. So you can create a new service within the navbar library called NavbarService which can have providedIn: 'root'  so that you can send events through this singleton service from your main application.
